# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was working on a hibernate project in eclipse. I put all of the jars files including Mysql connector jar in the WEB-INF lib folder. When I try to run the code, it throws an error.

Exception

> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
>   connection
>     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
>     org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
>     first.doPost(first.java:37)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample
>     java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
>     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
>     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
>     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
>     first.doPost(first.java:37)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52

[image: Image of jar file locations]

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory name="factory">

        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

        </property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</property>

        <property name="connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="connection.password">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="user" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try this connection

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: thanks but its throw an error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Comment: What reasons do you have for thinking this is the solution?

Comment: Bro same issue also comes me so I change this connection it works.

Comment: i try using it but throw an exception :Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".